# Ошибка генерации случайных цветов в 16-цатитеричной системе

Tags: javascript

Здравствуюте, в Macromedia Dreamweaver MX 2004, нашёл готовую функцию для генерации случайных цветов заднего фона и слегка изменил, чтобы изменялся не фон документа, а фон объекта с идом objid (но думаю, что это никак не влияет на мою проблему):

```
function randomBgColor(objid) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(objid);
    var r, g, b;
    r = decToHex(randomNumber(256) - 1);
    g = decToHex(randomNumber(256) - 1);
    b = decToHex(randomNumber(256) - 1);
    obj.style.backgroundColor = "#" + r + g + b;
}
```

она ещё использует функции:

```
function randomNumber(limit) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * limit);
}

function decToHex(dec) {
    var hexStr = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    var low = dec % 16;
    var high = (dec - low) / 16;
    hex = "" + hexStr.charAt(high) + hexStr.charAt(low);
    return hex;
}
```

и когда стал много раз ею пользоваться, оказалось, что иногда она генерирует число, не входящее в описание цветов CSS, и Firefox говорит:

> `Предупреждение: Ожидалось определение цвета, но найдено «#04F06».  Ошибка при анализе значения свойства «background-color».  Потерянное объявление.`
> `Источник: file://localhost/D:/Rproject/dancing%20div%27s/index.htm`
> `Строка: 0`

или даже

> `Ошибка: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIChannel.contentType]"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/components/FeedProcessor.js :: FP_onStartRequest :: line 1440"  data: no]`
> `Источник: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/components/FeedProcessor.js`
> `Строка: 1440`

А Internet Explorer вообще отказывается работать дальше после появления такого "цвета". Как исправить функцию, чтобы она не генерировала "неправильные цвета"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
randomNumber(256)-1 = -1..255
```

Исправьте на

```
randomNumber(255)
```

И все должно работать.

Как вариант в decToHex добавить проверку

```
dec = Math.round(dec);
if (dec < 0) dec = 0;
if (dec > 255) dec = 255;
```

Comment: Спасибо! randomNumber(255) помагло!И как такие "умные" разработчики Dreamweawer не додумались до этого! :)

Answer (score 1):

Я в js не силен, но думаю, что ошибка возникает тогда, когда randomNumber дает ноль.
Тогда на вход decToHex идет отрицательное число, и оно не входит в строку, тем самым давая 1-символьное предсталение числа, выдавая 5-символьное представление цвета, на котором и ломается браузер.

randomNumber(256) будет генерировать числа от 0 до 255 включительно, что полностью покрывает диапазон 8-битного канала